# how to make math operations on $_POST varibales in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, math

Ok so I have this form that send his values to a PHP file, the PHP file get the values in $_POST method.
for example:

```
$min = $_POST['time_min'];
```

Now I want to take this varibale, to multiply it by 60, and than to sent it to a SQL function.

I tried to do something like this:

```
$time = ($min * 60) + $sec;
$result = update_video($time);
```

And in the SQL:

```
$query = "UPDATE video SET  
time='".$time."'
WHERE video_id='".$video_id."'  
";
```

But it just won't updated.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please edit you post and add the complete form and php code here?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you end up with something like

```
UPDATE video SET
time='600000'
WHERE video_id='17'
```

However, I assume both `time` and `video_id` are defined as `INTEGER`, so quotes are messing you up.

Also, http://bobby-tables.com/.

Comment: `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--` ... great! :-)

Comment: I treid to remove the quotes but what I get is:
Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: I have no idea where you're getting an array. Can you do a `print_r($time)` and `print_r($video_id)`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `$_POST` value is a `String`. You've to cast it to an `Integer` first.

Try [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
$time = (intval($min) * 60) + $sec); // make sure $sec is an Integer as well.
```

By the way: 
Take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Your `SQL` doesn't look secure.

Good luck!

Comment: PHP has as one of its design goals (silly in my opinion, but goals nonetheless) that the programmer should rarely feel the distinction between strings and numbers, and that they autoconvert at a drop of a hat; so I doubt that lack of casting is the problem.